# android.R.color.transparent not fully transparent

Tags: android, listview, colors, background, android-listview

In my application, I apply the transparent background to my `ListView`'s CustomListItem at runtime. For that I use, `convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);`. It works and shows transparency. But that is not fully transparent as there is some kind of shade to the background. I also tried putting my own transparent color with the values `#80000000` and `#00000000` but the result is worse. What can I do to get the fully transparent color?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`android.R.color.transparent` is a resource id (referring to a transparent color definition) - `View.setBackgroundColor(int)` expects an actual int color.

Use [View.setBackgroundResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) instead, which will load the actual color from resources.

Comment: worked, but why it's not working the obvious way is still a mystery.

Answer (score 27):

Set this attribute to your listview in xml file

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and also apply the transparent background to your ListView's CustomListItem at runtime. 
For that you have use,

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Thanks

Comment: No man. Read my question. `convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);` was not working. Read @antonyt answer. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

OR

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this from now in your xml's files when you want transparency in your views:

```
android:background="@null"
```

You are going to get a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```