# @android:color/transparent does not work

Tags: android, transparency

**Please note**

This is not a question for the Activity/Theme or Manifest, its a `include layout` issue.

**The Issue**

In all my layouts I have included `progress_bar.xml` layout which has the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80ffffff"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:adjustViewBounds="true"-->
        <!--android:background="#80ffffff"-->
        <!--android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"-->
        <!--android:visibility="visible" />-->



        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/defaultBigProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:indeterminate="false" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/defaultSmallProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When I include it in some of my other layouts **at the end of the xml files** like this

```
  <include
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        layout="@layout/progress_bar"
        android:background="#80ffffff"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

The `progress_bar` takes up the entire screen and completely overlays on the other view without any **transparency** at all.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-on-android/17984430) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988671/android-r-color-transparent-not-fully-transparent) recommendations from other SO questions, non work.

These dont work

- android:background="@android:color/transparent"
- convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: I noticed that the same thing works  on activities with `drawer` layout

Comment: add `android:background="@null"`

Comment: I tried it, does not work

Comment: thanks this helps.. else the question wont get any attention. I spent a lot of effort to ensure that its not a duplicate.